# Finding county to a road using STContains

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, spatial, spatial-index

Running SQL Server 2014 Standard

I have about 1 million linestring (represent roads) and 98 polygons (counties). I want to update what county the road belongs to. My query:

```
UPDATE RAW_HERE
SET COUNTY = RAW_HERE_COUNTY.POLYGON_NM
FROM [dbo].[RAW_HERE_PROCESSED_SINGLE] AS RAW_HERE
INNER JOIN [RAW_HERE_D91_COUNTY] as RAW_HERE_COUNTY ON (RAW_HERE_COUNTY.[Shape].STContains(RAW_HERE.[Shape]) = 1)
```

This query has been running for 3 hours and counting, and I have verified it is using the spatial index on `RAW_HERE_D91_COUNTY`

`RAW_HERE_PROCESSED_SINGLE` contains the linestrings (their geometry column is [shape]) `RAW_HERE_D91_COUNTY` contains the polygon counties their geometry column is also [shape].

Is there an faster way to do this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure that you want `STContains()` and not `STIntersects()`? The former checks to see if (in your case) the road is fully within the county whereas the latter checks whether any part of the road is in the county. A lot of roads I know span more than one county, so I think having a road only have one county seems like a weird data model to me.  Additionally, I can see the server having to do more work for `STContains()` over `STIntersects()`, but that's just a gut feeling.

Comment: If a road intersects two counties then which county would it get? My plan was to first populate ones who were fully contained and then deal with edge cases were they span multiple.

Comment: Exactly my point. Either way, thinking on this more I was wondering if it's the actual update that's taking so long. But it looks like you reached the same conclusion with your self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes only 5 minute to make a primary key to county code lookup, so joining on county rather than joining county on roads seems the way to go

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#OBJECTCOUNTY](
    OBJECTID int PRIMARY KEY,
    [County] [nvarchar](105) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] 

INSERT INTO [#OBJECTCOUNTY]
SELECT RAW_HERE.OBJECTID, RAW_HERE_COUNTY.POLYGON_NM as County
FROM [RAW_HERE_D93_COUNTY] as RAW_HERE_COUNTY
LEFT JOIN [RAW_HERE_D93] as RAW_HERE ON (RAW_HERE_COUNTY.[Shape].STContains(RAW_HERE.[Shape]) = 1)
WHERE RAW_HERE.[Shape] IS NOT NULL
```

Then just update based on the table.